# I am trying to implement the strategy design pattern in the below snippet using Java 8 .Looking for better ways to implement?

Tags: java, design-patterns, java-8, functional-programming

I have below service implementation :-

```
package Java8.controller;

import java.util.function.Function;

public class ServiceImpl implements ITicket {

    Function<Integer,Double> ticketCal;

    public ServiceImpl(Function<Integer,Double> ticketCal){
        this.ticketCal= ticketCal;
    }

    @Override
    public double calculateFare(int quantity) {
        return ticketCal.apply(quantity);
    }

}
```

Below are the strategies that I have created :-

Recliner ticket strategy :-

```
package Java8.controller;

import java.util.function.Function;

public interface ReclinerTicketStrategy {

    default Function<Integer,Double> reclinerTicketStrategy(){

        return (noOfTickets)->{
            return noOfTickets * 200.00;
        };
    }
}
```

VIP Ticket strategy :-

```
package Java8.controller;

import java.util.function.Function;

public interface VipTicketStrategy {

    default Function<Integer,Double> vipTicketStrategy(){

         return (noOfTickets)->{
             return noOfTickets*400.00;
        };

    }
}
```

Below is the main class which is using the strategy :-

```
package Java8.controller;

public class Main implements ReclinerTicketStrategy {

    public Main(){

        ITicket ticketsVip = new ServiceImpl(reclinerTicketStrategy());
        System.out.println(ticketsVip.calculateFare(5));

}

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Main main = new Main();
    }


}
```

My question is whether is this the correct way of housing the strategy function in the interface as a default method? OR are there better ways to have it?

Answer (score 2):

Strategies should *implement* the abstraction needed by the service. In this case, the service needs a `Function<Integer,Double>` so then a strategy would be...

```
class ReclinerTicketStrategy implements Function<Integer,Double> {
    @Override
    public Double apply(Integer noOfTickets) {
        return noOfTickets * 200.0;
    }
}
```

The service is then instantiated as, 
`ITicket reclinerTicket = new ServiceImpl(new ReclinerTicketStrategy());`

Of course, if you don't need to reuse the strategy, then a lambda is sufficient. 
`ITicket reclinerTicket = new ServiceImpl(noOfTickets -> noOfTickets * 200.0);`

Answer (score 0):

You did kind of define a strategy here. But You should have defined a common interface more representative of the bussiness like:

```
public interface TicketStrategy {
    Double fare(final Integer quantity);
}
```

You can make it a FunctionalInterface if you want:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface TicketStrategy {
    Double fare(final Integer quantity);
}
```

Then you implements like you did:

```
public class TicketStrategies {

    public static final TicketStrategy VIP = noOfTickets -> noOfTickets * 400.00;
    public static final TicketStrategy RECLINER = noOfTickets-> noOfTickets * 200.00;
}
```

Then your main looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ITicket ticketsVip = new ServiceImpl(RECLINER));
    System.out.println(ticketsVip.calculateFare(5));
}
```

What you could do is to use it with a factory pattern like this:

```
public class TicketStrategyFactory {

    private static final Map<String, TicketStrategy> STRATEGIES;

    static {
        final HashMap<String, TicketStrategy> strategies = new HashMap<>();
        strategies.put("vip", TicketStrategies.VIP);
        strategies.put("recliner", TicketStrategies.RECLINER);
        STRATEGIES = Collections.unmodifiableMap(strategies);
    }

    public TicketStrategyFactory() {

    }

    public TicketStrategy create(String type) {
        TicketStrategy strategy = STRATEGIES.get(type);
        if (strategy == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown strategy " + type);
        }
        return strategy;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TicketStrategyFactory factory = new TicketStrategyFactory();
    ITicket ticketsVip = new ServiceImpl(factory.create("vip"));
    System.out.println(ticketsVip.calculateFare(5));
}
```

you can go further by leveraging function composition like this:

```
public class TicketStrategies {

    public static final TicketStrategy RECLINER = noOfTickets -> noOfTickets * 200.00;
    public static final TicketStrategy VIP = noOfTickets -> RECLINER.fare(noOfTickets) * 200;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it violate the OCP? Let's say in case we want to add another strategy then we will have to modify TicketStrategyFactory and do something like strategies.put("recliner", <<new strategy>>); and also add a new strategy in this class?

Comment: Also is it a good idea to house all the strategies in the same class TicketStrategies ? Since in case we want to add any new strategy we will have to modify this class? 
Is this like violation of the OCP again?

Comment: it's a sample for you to get the ideas. But yeah you could make it quite easy to add strategies to the factory ! And you can put the strategies in other places !